# Unable to map user defined database function in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple database function that accepts two integer arguments and returns a date. I am trying to map the function in EF Core so I can access it from my code.

I have read numerous articles about this and have tried the following:

In dbContext I tried defining the function as follows:

```
[DbFunction("GetLastPlayDate")]
public static bool GetLastPlayDate(int GroupId, int PlayerId)
{
    throw new Exception(); // this code doesn't get executed; the call is passed through to the database function
}
```

Then, in the `OnModelCreating` method, I did the following:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(dbContext)
            .GetMethod(nameof(GetLastPlayDate), new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }))
            .HasName("GetLastPlayDate");
```

I added a migration. Then I was expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
var date = db.GetLastPlayDate(1,2)
```

The function is not defined. Help please!

I tried adding the function but it isn't available from my `dbContext`.

Comment: Remove `static` modifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call DbFunction with EF core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269315/call-dbfunction-with-ef-core-2-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the C# function `GetLastPlayDate(1,2)` within a Linq query. For example see the code below:

```
var db = serviceProvider.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<DatabaseContext>();
   
var games = db.Games.Select(x => DatabaseContext.GetLastPlayDate(4, 6) == true).ToList();
```

However, If you want to work around it, do the following:

1- Create a class that has the function name, with one property that has the same return type

```
public class GetLastPlayDate
{
  public bool Result { get; set; }
}
```

2-In your DbContext add the created class as DbSet

```
internal class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
            public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options){ }
    
            public DbSet<GetLastPlayDate> LastPlayDate{ get; set; }
}
```

3- Inside the function `OnModelCreating` Map it like the following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GetLastPlayDate>(e => e.HasNoKey());
```

4- Finally, Execute the function as follows:

```
int val1 = 3; int val2 = 4;
    
bool? functionResult;
functionResult = db.LastPlayDate.FromSqlInterpolated($"select   dbo.GetLastPlayDate ({val1}, {val2}) as Result").FirstOrDefault()?.Result;
```

Comment: I tried removing the Static qualifier as suggested by Petrov.  After doing so, I can use db.GetLastDate, however it throws a not implemented exception.  Don't know why.

Comment: The solution by Ati works, however it causes a table to be created when I add-migration and update-database from the Package Manager Console.  How can I prevent the table from being created?